# Can I use applescript to click buttons in background?

Tags: macos, applescript

Sorry for this generic and probably bad-written question. I've never programmed in applescript, but I'm quite familiar with other coding language.

I'm in the need of clicking on 2 sequential button inside the lobby of a software (when you click the first a popup appears and we should click 'ok'). However things are a little bit more complicated then this because:

1) the lobby of this program isn't in foreground: it's covered by other windows opened. (I don't have experience so I don't know if this represent a problem).

2) there should be a timer and the program should click this button at regular intervals.

Is this feasible with applescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can usually interact with windows even if they were on the background or displayed by a hidden application. Finding UI elements is the harder part.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder" to tell window 1
    -- properties of UI elements
    -- {class, value} of UI elements of UI elements
    -- buttons of group 1
    repeat
        click button 2
        delay 3
    end repeat
end tell
```

UI scripting doesn't work unless access for assistive devices is enabled in the accessibility preferences.